# How to parse the file name and rename in Matlab

Tags: file, parsing, matlab, names

I am reading a .xls file and then procesing it inside and rewriting it in the end of  my program.  I was wondering if someone can help me  to parse the dates 
as my input file name is like  file_1_2010_03_03.csv

and i want my outputfile to be

newfile_2010_03_03.xls

is there a way to incorporate in matlab program so i do not have to manually write the command
xlswrite('newfile_2010_03_03.xls', M);
everytime and change the dates as i input files with  diff dates
like 
file_2_2010_03_04.csv.

Maybe i was not clear>
  I am using uigetfile to input 3 diff  files in format
file_1_2010_03_03.csv,file_2_2010_03_03.csv,file_3_2010_03_03.csv

Now i am processing the file inside my program and writing 4 output files
with names  newfileX_3_2010_03_03.xls,newfileXY_3_2010_03_03.xls,newfileXZ_3_2010_03_03.xls,
newfileYZ_3_2010_03_03.xls

so my dates are not current date , but i need that from the input file and append that to newname  for my xlswrite.

so was wondering if there is a way i can write a generic

xlswrite ('xxx ' M);
which will pick the name i want instead of me having 2 modify the name' xxx' everytime i input a new file

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: So, do you want to include the integer after "file_" in the new file name, or just the date?

Comment: Just the date as my output has totally diff names except the same date in the end

Comment: Also, do you end up outputting *4* files or *12* files from the 3 that you enter?

Comment: I am not using the loop as  i process 3 files inside my program separately. and its only in the end when i xls write i want to recall  the intergers corresoponding to the dates of original files.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I misunderstood what you meant with 'file_1', 'file_2' - I thought the numbers 1 and 2 had some kind of importance.

```
oldFileName = 'something_2010_03_03.csv';
%# extract the date (it's returned in a cell array
theDate = regexp(oldFileName,'(\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2})','match');
newFileName = sprintf('newfile_%s.xls',theDate{1});
```

**Older Version with Explanations**

I assume that the date in all your files is the same. So your program would go

```
%# load the files, put the names into a cell array
fileNames = {'file_1_2010_03_03.csv','file_2_2010_03_03.csv','file_3_2010_03_03.csv'};

%# parse the file names for the number and the date
%# This expression looks for the n-digit number (1,2, or 3 in your case) and puts
%# it into the field 'number' in the output structure, and it looks for the date
%# and puts it into the field 'date' in the output structure
%# Specifically, \d finds digits, \d+ finds one or several digits, _\d+_
%# finds one or several digits that are preceded and followed by an underscore
%# _(?<number>\d+)_ finds one or several digits that are preceded and follewed 
%# by an underscore and puts them (as a string) into the field 'number' in the 
%# output structure. The date part is similar, except that regexp looks for 
%# specific numbers of digits
tmp = regexp(fileNames,'_(?<number>\d+)_(?<date>\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2})','names');
nameStruct = cat(1,tmp{:}); %# regexp returns a cell array. Catenate for ease of use

%# maybe you want to loop, or maybe not (it's not quite clear from the question), but 
%# here's how you'd do with a loop. Anyway, since the information about the filenames
%# is conveniently stored in nameStruct, you can access it any way you want.
for iFile =1:nFiles
   %# do some processing, get the matrix M

   %# and create the output file name
   outputFileX = sprintf('newfileX_%s_%s.xls',nameStruct(iFile).number,nameStruct(iFile).date);
   %# and save
   xlswrite(outputFileX,M)
end
```

See [regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html) for more details on how to use them. Also, you may be interested in
[uipickfiles](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10867-uipickfiles-uigetfile-on-steroids) to replace uigetfile.

Comment: What does 'd+' do?? what does the '+' do?

Comment: @Paul: I have added a bit more explanation. Hope it makes things clearer!

Comment: lets make it simple

i use 

[a,patha]=uigetfile({'*.csv'},'Select the file','c:\ Data'); 
File_selected=a
file1=[patha a]; 


oldFileName = a; 
% newFileName = regexprep(oldFileName,'pwr_avg_\d+_','newfile_')

when i do this it gives me new file name as 
newfile_03_03.csv
why did it miss 2010 as my initial file name was 
file_1_2010_03_03.csv

Comment: Well, if your old file name was 'pwr_avg_2010_03_03.csv', then newFileName will be 'newfile_03_03.csv', because 2010 matches _\d+_, i.e. multiple digits surrounded by underscores. What are your file names exactly? Note that if all you need is the dates, the regexp in my EDIT works perfectly fine.

Comment: I have diff file names  but the format is the same
XX_2010_03_03.csv , All of them have diff XX

Comment: @Paul: There's your problem. We were assuming that XX would always be XX_#, where # is some *number*, because those were the examples you gave above. Our solutions are snagging 2010 as the number we expect *before* the date, thus leaving it out of the date.

Comment: @Paul: now my solution just extracts the date. Note that the date should always be (4 digits)(underscore)(2 digits)(underscore)(2 digits).

Comment: @gnoice: I do not care for XX all i want is  _2010_03_03
to make newfile_2010_03_03.xls

Comment: @Jonas:  Woo hoo it works!! Thanks a lot Jonas. Have a good day

Comment: +1: After all the reclarifications of the question details, it look like REGEXP is a more compact solution than TEXTSCAN. ;)

Comment: @Paul: a nice thing to do is upvoting/accepting an answer if it turns out to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you want to build the file name based on the date or not. If you just want to change the name of the file you read, you can do this:

```
filename = 'file_1_2010_03_03.csv';
newfilename = strrep(filename,'file_1_', 'newfile_');
xlswrite(newfilename,M)
```

UPDATE:

To parse the date from the file name:

```
dtstr = strrep(filename,'file_1_','');
dtstr = strrep(dtstr,'.csv','');
DT = datenum(dtstr,'yyyy_mm_dd');
disp(datestr(DT))
```

To build file name based on date (today's for example):

```
filename = ['file_', datestr(date,'yyyy_mm_dd') '.csv'];
```

Comment: I see, I missed that the number after file changes. Go with other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If your 3 files from [UIGETFILE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/uigetfile.html) all have the same date in their name, then you can just use one of them to do the following (after you have processed all your data from the 3 files):

```
fileName = 'file_1_2010_03_03.csv';          %# One of your 3 file names
data = textscan(fileName,'%s',...            %# Split string at '_' and '.'
                'Delimiter','_.');
fileString = sprintf('_%s_%s_%s.xls',..      %# Make the date part of the name
                     data{1}{(end-3):(end-1)});
xlswrite(['newfileX' fileString],dataX);     %# Output "X" data
xlswrite(['newfileXY' fileString],dataXY);   %# Output "XY" data
xlswrite(['newfileXZ' fileString],dataXZ);   %# Output "XZ" data
xlswrite(['newfileYZ' fileString],dataYZ);   %# Output "YZ" data
```

The function [TEXTSCAN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) is used to break up the old file name at the points where `'_'` or `'.'` characters occur. The function [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) is then used to put the pieces for the date back together.

Comment: Is there anyway the output file does not have the .csv?
i mean with the above code i  get new file as 
newfileXY_2010_03_03.csv.xls

Comment: @Paul: I fixed the typo in the code. It should work how you want it to now.

Comment: I liked your earlier ans it was simpler :P

Comment: with the code my output gives me right name  minus 2010. why am i missing it?
I get it when i input like you did within comma  but i am using uiget. so for me my currentFile= a

Comment: @Paul: I simplified the code since your comments suggested you were processing the 3 files first, then outputting 4 files. The above code works for me without any problems, so you should double check what your variable `a` contains (it should have the same format as `fileName` in my above code).

Comment: Yes this code works , but my output looks like newfileX_03_03.xls i do get the full if i manully input fileName = 'file_1_2010_03_03.csv' but i input by uiget like [a,patha]=uigetfile({'*.csv'},'Select the file','c:\ Data'); File_selected=a file1=[patha a]; fileName = a;

and my a=file_1_2010_03_03.csv , which i am checking while i run

Comment: @Paul: Now that you have specified that the `'file_1'` part of the name could be anything, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, all of these files are sitting in a directory somewhere and you'd like to process them in batch. You can use code like this to read the files in a particular directory and find the ones that end in 'csv'. That way, you don't have to change your code at all if you'd like to process a new file -- you just drop it in the directory and run your program.

```
extension = 'csv';

files = dir();  % e.g. use current directory

% find files with the proper extension
extLength = length(extension);
for k = 1:length(files)
    nameLength = length(files(k).name);
    if nameLength > extLength
        if (files(k).name((nameLength - extLength + 1):nameLength) == extension)
            a(k).name
            % process file here...
        end
    end
end
```

You can make it more compact by incorporating the regexp processing that Jonas suggested.